# Nextjs + expressjs + Azure Web App : two factor authentication with express ('fs' can't be used on client side)

Tags: reactjs, express, azure-devops, next.js, azure-webapps

Stack : next.js/express.js/typescript/nodemon

I have a dependency on [azure devops api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-node-api) which seems to be using 'fs' under the hood. So I can't use this library in any of the pages (including in getInitialProps).
I created a custom route (call it "get_data") in express server which provides me with the data. I call this route in getInitialProps of the page that will render the data (call it data.tsx) .

The whole app is behind two factor authentication in azure web apps. when get_data call is made in getInitialProps, I get a 401. Note that the origin is the same for serving the page and the get_data api.

1. Is there a way to pass current auth context when I make the get_data api call ?
2. In the express api, the method currently looks like this :

```
server.get('/get_data', (_req, res) => {
  let ado = new azure_devops() // this uses the azure-devop-api package 
  ado.get_data().then((data) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(data) // return data as json 
  })
});
```

Is there a way to merge the two (page and data serving) like the following (so I don't have to make extra api call with auth setup) ?

```
server.get('/data', (req, res) => { //note the change in route that serves the page data.tsx 
  const actualPage = '/data'; 
  let ado = new azure_devops() // this uses the azure-devop-api package 
  ado.get_data().then((data) => { 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    res.write(data) // BUT this is where method returns instead i want to just add to the response body 
    app.render(req, res, actualPage); // THIS is not executed (so the page doesn't get rendered) 
  }) 
});
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466982/next-js-express-session-new-session-for-every-request-made-inside-getinitialp).

Still making the API request from getInitialProps. I was missing adding cookie from the context.

```
const res = await fetch('http://' + context.req.headers.host + '/get_data', {
    headers: {
      cookie: context.req.headers.cookie, // WAS MISSING THIS
    }
  });
```